# xaf detailview in add or edit mode

Tags: c#, xaf

I have a DetailView that opens from Navigation list. It opens in view mode normally there is only a specific data for setting. I want to make sure that when there is no record in the database it will be opened in add view and when there is a record it opens in edit view. How can this be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you need is a Singleton. Here's how you implement it: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112916

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I used another way but this also helps